# ZonalStatisticsAsTable misses 245 polygons out of 3108! using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have many .ncf files that I read as raster layers and then do zonal statistics to have mean and sd values over each of 3108 CONUS counties. But the final standalone table is missing 245 counties. This is how the raster layer and the counties look together. You see that the raster covers all the polygons

[image: The raster layer and the 3108 polygons to calculate zonal statistics]

And this is missing counties from the resulted zonal statistics. The red counties are missing from the result, that I can not find any reason for!

[image: pinker colors are missing counties]

This is my code that loops over different files with same rasters only different values in cells and the same shape file for zonal boundaries.

```
# Set the analysis environments
env.workspace = r"C:\ArcGIS_projects\PM25"

rasrtersFolder = r"C:\ArcGIS_projects\PM25\V4NA03\\"
zonalOutFolder = r"C:ArcGIS_projects\PM25\zonal_stats\\"

variable = "PM25"
XDimension = "LON"
YDimension = "LAT"
outRasterLayer = "PM25"
bandDimmension = ""
dimensionValues = ""
valueSelectionMethod = ""
cellRegistration = ""

# for zonal statistics
inZoneData = 'CONUS_counties_2016_WGS1984'
zoneField = 'GEOID'
inValueRaster = 'PM25'

for fileName in files:
    # Reading netcdf file into raster layer
    inNetCDFFile = rasrtersFolder + fileName

    # Execute MakeNetCDFRasterLayer
    arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, XDimension, YDimension,
                               outRasterLayer, bandDimmension, dimensionValues, 
                               valueSelectionMethod, cellRegistration)

    # Now doing zonal statistics
    outName = fileName.split('.')[0]
    outTable = zonalOutFolder + outName+'.dbf'

    outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, inValueRaster,
                                  outTable, "DATA", "MEAN_STD")

    # Set local variables
    inTable = outName
    outLocation = r"C:\Users\babak.jfard\ArcGIS_projects\PM25\zonal_stats_csv"
    outTable = outName.split('-')[0] + ".csv"

    # Execute TableToTable
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(inTable, outLocation, outTable)
    
    arcpy.management.Delete('PM25')
    arcpy.management.Delete(outName)
    arcpy.management.Delete(outTable)
```

the files to reproduce can be found here: (All projection are set to WGS1984 to align with the ncdf files)

- [The shapefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yptnK5o7bOsFvMyIXqMfDyo3-w6rFb_1/view?usp=sharing)
- [Sample of one of ncd files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ZKcxrmhnVdTM2NzLnAM5ZQcYOY5hUu_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Things to double check 1. Did you have any counties selected when you ran the zonal stats tool? 2. How are NaN/Null values being handled?

Comment: 1. No, I did not.

Comment: 2. It is to ignore NoData

Comment: I think this might be my upgrade to ArcGIS Pro 2.8.2 last night!! Two weeks ago I did one sample of these files and it worked perfectly. I just executed Zonal Statistics on the very same files, and it has 245 missing!! Is it possible?

Comment: Reduce cell size of your raster.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. Note that bug reports should go to the vendor (Esri Tech Support), since they have no way to track details and interested parties by a web post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had projected my shapefile to the projection of my raster files (NetCDF). But the raster files did not have any projected coordinate system (only contained Geographic Coordinate!).
So, I solved it the other way. Now before doing the zonal statistics, I project each raster into my shapefile projection that contains both GCS and PCS, using this command:

```
arcpy.management.ProjectRaster
```